# Difference between Backbone View instance and the view's `this`

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, memory-leaks

See my code here:

```
var DemoView = Backbone.View.extend({

  initialize: function() {
    this.render();
  },

  render: function() {
    var template = _.template('<p>text</p> \
      <p>text</p> \
      <p id="close">close</p>');
    this.$el.html(template());
    $('#demoContainer').html(this.el);
  },

  events: {
    'click #close': 'close'
  },

  close: function() {
    this.remove();
  }

});
```

If I use this code below and manually click the `click` button to remove the view:

```
(function() {

  var demoView = new DemoView();

})();
```

Then I check the memory leaks, there comes the result:
[image]

But if I use this code below and wait 5 seconds for the view to remove it automatic:

```
(function() {

  var demoView = new DemoView();

  setTimeout(function() {
    demoView.remove();
  }, 5000);

})();
```

I got none of memory leak:

[image]

Can anyone explain why ?

Version of libs: Backbone 1.1.2, jQuery 1.9.1

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15638368/memory-leak-when-deleting-items-from-dom-using-backbone

Comment: So, I need not care about it ? For jQuery will handle it ?