# Backbone & Marionette Memory Leak

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I have a backbone app that I can’t figure out where this memory leak is coming from. I have a page, doing nothing (login screen). I’ve already removed every event listener and it’s basically just a view with a form… But if I do a heap snapshot on chrome and then 2 seconds later do another, it still shows detached doms.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/5f33hgbrc3b5z8y/Screenshot%202014-06-05%2008.14.20.png

I'm using the same app breakdown as seen here, and I also see they have the same problem:
http://davidsulc.github.io/marionette-gentle-introduction/#contacts

Thoughts?

Comment: It's possibly due to jQuery caching (specifically Sizzle). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15638368/memory-leak-when-deleting-items-from-dom-using-backbone The space for this caching is limited, so unused elements will eventually get garbage collected.

Comment: Is there a way to tell if it's a cached item or a real leak?

Comment: According to the answer, the cached elements start with `sizzle`

Comment: I'm not using Sizzle and so none of mine say that.

Comment: You probably are since sizzle is the selector engine of jquery (built-in)