# Backbone memory leak Detached DOM

Tags: backbone.js, memory

i was having a look at Detached DOM trees with profiler in Chrome Dev tools, and while testing the code below i guess i've found a memory leak.
The workflow is the following:

1. load the page
2. take a heap snapshot => there aren't any detached dom trees
3. click on filter event, which filters the collection and render the table again
4. take a heap snapshot and compare with the previous one => there are a detached tree

After debugging the code i found that the problem is with the following line

```
this.listenTo(this.model, "clearView", this.remove); //Line with problem
```

if i removed this line there are no detached dom trees, otherwise i have the detached dom trees. Am i missing to unbind something? Any help will be appretiated.

Thanks.

```
var Post = { Views: {} };

Post.Model = Backbone.Model.extend({

    initialize: function() {
    },

    destroyView: function() {
    }
});

Post.Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Post.Model,
    url: '/posts'
});

Post.Views.ModelView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'tr',
    template:  APP.Templates.PostModel,

    initialize: function() {
        this.listenTo(this.model, "clearView", this.remove); //Line with problem
    },

    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    },

    remove: function() {
        console.log("remove");
    }
});

Post.Views.CollectionView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: APP.Templates.PostCollection,

    events : {
        "click .filter":"filter",
        "click .delete":"clear"
    },

    initialize: function() {
        this.toRenderModels = this.collection.models;
    },

    filter: function() {
        this.toRenderModels = null;
        this.toRenderModels = this.collection.where({title: 'Post 1'});
        this.render();
    },

    clear: function() {
        this.toDeleteModel = this.collection.at(0);
    },

    render: function() {
        this.$el.empty();
        this.$el.html(this.template());
        _.each(this.toRenderModels, function(model) {
            this.$('table').append(new Post.Views.ModelView({model: model}).render().el);
            }, this);
        this.toRenderModels = null; 
        return this;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line you have marked as "line with problem" should be placed in View's constructor.

Most important here is to call remove method which removes element and stops listening to events.

```
remove: function() {
  this.$el.remove();
  this.stopListening();
  return this;
},
```

It's a default implementation, you don't have to copypaste it.

Related question: [Memory Leak when deleting items from DOM using backbone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15638368/memory-leak-when-deleting-items-from-dom-using-backbone)

Comment: Agree with your answer, i replace el.empty() with a removeViews() implementation so that stopListening is called and so events are unbound.